# Migrating web service from ColdFusion 8 to 10 issues

Tags: web-services, coldfusion

I have a web service that has been running on CF 8 for awhile now without issues. We've recently moved to CF10, and this web service no longer works. I've already tried switching the Axis setting to 1, it's still tossing errors. Has anyone else encountered this, or have an ideas on what else to look for here?

**Process**:

1. CF Server sends a web service request to App Server.
2. App Server processes request, generates another web service back to CF Server with SOAP data pushes, then replies back to the step 1 originating request with a boolean response on how its own web service request went.

**CF Server Errors**:

- The web service operation caused an invocation exception.The root cause was that: ClientAbortException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error.
- Cannot perform web service invocation [Method Name]. The fault returned when invoking the web service operation is: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/james/mime4j/MimeException

**App Server Error Logs**:

- com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Message send failed
- SEVERE: SAAJ0009: Message send failed
- com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Message send failed
- Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error writing to server

I've gone as far as modifying the App Server configuration to have it's web service request push out to the CF 8 server for processing, while still replying back to the originating request from the CF 10 server. This worked fine. It's definitely something with the requests or my CF 10 web service config.

I can't post any of the code examples unfortunately.

**24 Sept 13 Update**
I've tried various combinations of v1 and v2 in the CF admin, with wsdl and wsdl2, and the application.cfc setup. The app that is interacting with this service has given me the ability to modify a variety of parameters for soap versioning and some internal items. I can get the two services to talk with a bare bones connection of give me your soap and I'll toss a YES back. Whenever I try to use the full request it seems to never actually hit my web service, and gets stopped somewhere by CF. I see no logging on it other than in the web service log.

Comment: I've noticed that the request is coming in to CF 10 from an app that is using MTOM with its service calls. I'm wondering if the mime4j issue is because CF doesn't have this library by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. The ColdFusion connector was causing the fault. After installing ColdFusion 10 and patching, I had run the wsconfig to rebuild the connector. I had either done this incorrectly, or for some reason it didn't take. I ran it this morning, removed the connector, re-added it.... everything working fine now. Very frustrating.